# python script executed from php gives error

Tags: php, python, linux, xampp, debian

On my debian i run xampp. I want to execute a python script using php shell_exec.
This is my php code:

```
shell_exec("/opt/lampp/htdocs/news/hello.py 2>1 &");
```

When i run it from the browser i get this error:

```
/usr/bin/python: /opt/lampp/lib/libz.so.1: no version information available (required by /usr/bin/python)
```

If i run it from the terminal window using this: `php /opt/lampp/htdocs/page/index.php` it works without any problems.
So any ideas how can i make it work from the browser?
Thanks

Comment: this is not the same shell. What the one shell has is missing in the other. Maybe just an environment variable or one of it's values? Comparing booth environments might lead you a way in troubleshooting this more easily. Sorry I don't know python that well that I would know what that error message *exactly means*.

Comment: Maybe searching the internet for the error message is hepful, it seems you are not the first one seeing it: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1905963

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing xampp comes with it's own libraries instead of using the system libraries, and that probably means it's setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to it's local library directory.

This will also cause other programs started from php to use this libraries, which they may not be compatible with.

To veryfy that, try `system("env");`, that sould show you all the exported environment variables. If `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is set, use:

```
shell_exec("LD_LIBRARY_PATH= /opt/lampp/htdocs/news/hello.py 2>1 &");
```

That unsets it before running the python script.

Comment: i get this 
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/docvert/docvert-cli.py", line 12, in <module>
    import core.docvert
  File "/docvert/core/docvert.py", line 9, in <module>
    import docvert_libreoffice
  File "/docvert/core/docvert_libreoffice.py", line 18, in <module>
    import uno
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/uno.py", line 52, in <module>
    _g_ctx = pyuno.getComponentContext( )
SystemError: Error during bootstrapping uno (RuntimeException):cannot open file:///root/.ure/types.rdb`

Comment: That means the python script is running now, but there is an different issue with the script itself, not directly related to this one. You should open a new question for that problem.